# MetaMask no longer injects web3

Tags: javascript, web3js, metamask

How to load web3 correctly ? this is my code:

```
async loadweb3() {
if (window.ethereum) {
  window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
  
  await window.ethereum.enable()
} else if  (window.web3) {
  window.web3 =new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider)
 
} else {
  window.alert(' Non-Ethereum browser detected, Ypu should consider trying Metamask')
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.web3` is deprecated. easies way is to use `@metamask/detect-provider` npm package

```
import detectEthereumProvider from "@metamask/detect-provider";

 const provider = await detectEthereumProvider();
      // only if provider is detected, create web3 instance and then create contract
      if (provider) {
        const web3 = new Web3(provider);
        const contract = ..........whatever create contract api u are using
        .....
```